# Trim Function doesn't Work

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, trim

Hi (sorry for my english xD),

I'm taking data of my DB in MySql, this data (pair of players in format 'Player 1 - Player 2'). I cut this with `explode` function by character `-` therefore I get 'Player 1 ' and ' Player 2' string. I try delete white spaces at the beginning and the end with trim function, but this don't work. I suspect that this trouble is similar to other with the `-` character, the normal `-` of my keyboard don't split the string with explode function, I had to go to PHPMyAdmin and copy the `-` character of the one existing string and paste this in the second explode function parameter, after this, explode function work.

I try the same of the `-` character (Login in PHPMyAdmin copy one whitespace and paste this as second parameter of `trim` function but this time don't work :( ).

Also try with `str_replace` function (no matter what the gaps are eliminated) and don't work, also try with `preg_replace` function etc... nothing has work because apparently the white space saved in DB isn't the same of my keyboard, I suspect that the problem is related with charset's or collations but I don't have idea what I should do, because the table, link, charset of PHP and other thing are in UTF-8 and utf8-spanish-ci collation and charset.

Aclaration: The input of the data is made by xdom (PHP) from other site not controlled for me.

```
<tbody>
<?php while ($partidos = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="center"><?php echo $partidos['fecha']; ?></td>
        <td><?php $participante = explode("₋", $partidos['jugadores']);
            $participante1 = trim($participante[0]);
            $participante2 = trim($participante[1]);

            echo trim($participante1) . "<br>vs<br>" . trim($participante2);
            ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($partidos['estado'] == 0) { ?> En Curso<?php } elseif ($partidos['estado'] == 1) {
                if ($partidos['alerta'] == 0) { ?> Terminado<?php } else { ?>Terminado - Error <i
                    class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><?php }
            } ?></td>
        <td><?php if ($partidos['alerta_medica'] == 1) { ?> Si <i class="fa fa-2 fa-medkit"
                                                                  style="color:#C00;"></i><?php } else { ?> No<?php } ?>
        </td>
        <?php if ($_SESSION['tipo'] == 1 || $_SESSION['tipo'] == 2) { ?>
            <td class="center">
            </td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

[image: Screenshot from command line]

Comment: did you try the Mysql trim or the PHP function?

Comment: The PHP function, is possible split the field string by '-' character and trim each resultant name in mysql?

Comment: in myphpadmin did you see a space or � ?

Comment: Normal spaces :S, the collation of the field is utf8-spanish-ci, i execute the queries:

mysqli_query($conexion,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($conexion,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

after of mysqli_connect and the PHP Charset is set to uft8 in php.ini

Comment: I would like to see your code ..  so I can determinate why it is not trimming those white space, can you please export your database and post one of the INSERT with these types of white spaces

Comment: This is the Dump of the last rows in the table:

`-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.3.11
-- Versión del servidor: 5.6.24
-- Versión de PHP: 5.6.8

-- Base de datos: '********'

-- Volcado de datos para la tabla ´informes´

INSERT INTO ´informes´ (´id´, ´estado´, ´fecha´, ´jugadores´,  ´alerta_medica´, ´completado´, ´alerta´) VALUES
(17187, 0, '2015-06-15 17:53:43', 'Kevin Anderson/Jeremy Chardy   ₋   Chris Guccione/Andre Sa',  0, 1, 0),
(17196, 0, '2015-06-15 18:26:46', 'Laura Siegemund/Renata Voracova   ₋   Irina Ramialison/Constance Sibille', 0, 1, 0)`

Comment: yes, I see the square symbol instead `-`, can you please, send the create database statement and the table create, I would like to replicate the issue on my computer

Comment: How do I do that? the comment length is limited here :/ is possible put this in one .zip file and paste the mega url here?

Comment: I just ask for the DDL for example `CREATE DATABASE ....` and `CREATE TABLE ....`

Comment: I just opened a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80621/trim-function-dont-work

Comment: My reputation don't permit to chat :(

Comment: Use the `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` function, not those SET queries.

Comment: Where does ` - ` come from?  Could it be an `em dash` instead of a `minus sign`?

Comment: @RickJames I replace the SET queries with you code, but this still not working. In't sure if is a minus sign but the problem whit it was solved copying the original sign and paste in the explode function, i still having problem whit the blanksppaces :(

Comment: Provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` to display the hex for some cell that is being improperly displayed.  (This will help diagnose whether the problem was with `INSERT` or with `SELECT`.)

Comment: Executing: **SELECT HEX(`jugadores`) FROM `informes` LIMIT 0,5**

4A616E204865726E79636820C2A020E2828B20C2A0C2A04164616D205061766C6173656B
4D6172636F204365636368696E61746F20C2A020E2828B20C2A0C2A04A61726D657265204A656E6B696E73
4879656F6E204368756E6720C2A020E2828B20C2A0C2A04E696C73204C616E676572
4D204572696B73736F6E2F5020526F73656E686F6C6D20C2A020E2828B20C2A0C2A04520476F6D657A2F4320536D697468
46616E677A686F75204C697520C2A020E2828B20C2A0C2A0426172626F7261204B72656A63696B6F7661

Comment: The same query without HEX(): **SELECT `jugadores` FROM `informes` LIMIT 0,5**

Jan Hernych   ₋   Adam Pavlasek
Marco Cecchinato   ₋   Jarmere Jenkins
Hyeon Chung   ₋   Nils Langer
M Eriksson/P Rosenholm   ₋   E Gomez/C Smith
Fangzhou Liu   ₋   Barbora Krejcikova

Comment: For more clarity, i just upload a screenshot of the result: [link](http://i.imgur.com/aZyQXg6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem thanks to @Rick James, watching the hexadecimal response of the database i noticed that two spaces are x20, but one is xC2 xA0. Reading in other post of stackoverflow, i found that xC2 xA0 is a Non-break space, but this is not recognized for the trim function. The solution was specify this as second parameter of the function:

```
$participante1 = trim($participante[0],"\x20,\xC2,\xA0");
$participante2 = trim($participante[1],"\x20,\xC2,\xA0");
```

Now the whitespaces are removed correctly :3

Thanks to all for give your help to solve this :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 3 blanks on either side of the special character split the strings by 3 spaces.

like this:

```
<?php

foreach( $strings as $string) {
    $players = explode("   ",$string);
    print "Player 1: " . $players[0]  . PHP_EOL;
    print "Player 2: " . $players[2]  . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, but the data is in format `Player 1   -   Player 2` after split this but the `-` sign the blank spaces remain at the last of the fisrt player name, and the beggining of the second player, the main problem is the initial whitespaces in the second player.

Comment: can you post the output of my code? can you post the result of this `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`jugadores\``

Comment: Sure, the output of you code is: **Player 1: O P Azcoitia/P G. Thombare   ₋   J Ladurner/N Verster 
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\public_html\site\dashboard.php on line 160
Player 2:** and the result of the query is: [link](http://i.imgur.com/9v5e5c6.png)